# What do I need to fix? C++

Tags: c++

The question goes as follows:

**Given integer suppliedSpoons, output:**

**"Full bin" if the number of spoons is greater than 38 and less than or equal to 55.**

**"Jumbo bin" if the number of spoons is greater than 103 and less than 115.**

**"Not efficient to ship" otherwise.**

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int suppliedSpoons;

   cin >> suppliedSpoons;  
   
   if((suppliedSpoons > 38) && (suppliedSpoons <= 55)){
     
 cout << "Full bin\n";
   
}
 
  if((suppliedSpoons > 103) && (suppliedSpoons < 115)){
 
     cout << "Jumbo bin\n";

   }

   else{

      cout << "Not efficient to ship\n";

   }

   return 0;

}
```

Whenever the test are being produced apperantly when the value of suppliedSpoons falls in the first if statement it will produce "Full bin" but it will also produce "Not effecient to ship" as well. What do I do to make it just produce "Full bin"?

Comment: You're missing an `else` after the first branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `else if` instead of `if` second time. like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   int suppliedSpoons;

   cin >> suppliedSpoons;  
   
   if((suppliedSpoons > 38) && (suppliedSpoons <= 55)){
     
 cout << "Full bin\n";
   
}
 
  else if((suppliedSpoons > 103) && (suppliedSpoons < 115)){
 
     cout << "Jumbo bin\n";

   }

   else{

      cout << "Not efficient to ship\n";

   }

   return 0;

}
```